# Why does the main site keep showing me "empty" ads?

Tags: bug, advertising

The "main" site keeps showing me "empty" ads, like this:

[image]

Why is this? Is this a defect, or is there simply no ad to show me? If there's no ad, why show me an empty box?

Comment: Do you have an adblocker on?

Comment: @10Rep No, but is it possible that the corporate network configuration or something could be interfering here? I do see *some* ads, just not all of them.

Comment: switch to a better adblocker, that removes them

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica Try inspecting that area where you see that. Could be a proxy issue where a network configration is blocking the ad.

Comment: Don't you see the 3d ship there?

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica maybe try a different employer to see if their network config is any better ....

Comment: It's puzzling that there is no [moar-ads-plz] tag, isn't it? Also, I'm suddenly hungry for peanuts...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to a brand safety company (probably DoubleVerify) blocking the ad from being shown. For some reason or another they have determined you aren't a real user, could be you are using a proxy, have an ad blocker running on most other sites, etc. I believe it could also be if they determine you are out of region for the ad (for instance you are in Canada but the ad is targeted to US only).

For more background information on ad blocking due to brand suitability/safety concerns, please read [this article on ExchangeWire](https://www.exchangewire.com/blog/2020/03/19/brand-suitability-demystifying-blocking-and-the-dv-clouds/).